# Cannot get tomcat 8 Up : Zip file exception

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

Did the following:

1. Installed new tomcat 8.0.23 and 8.0.36 and used.
2. Used both Java 8 and 7 (Changed java 8 versions update 45 and 91)
3. Changed permissions to 777 in the tomcat folder
4. Changed tomcat logging level to FINEST to get which zip file not getting opened. (does not provide the name)
5. These are container logs, if that helps, catalina.out
6. Used a bare tomcat and that gets up of course so no issues in the system. 100% something in my exploded war, but can't get what.

Can some one help ?

```
Stacktrace :

SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@488d192]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5088)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@24c77366]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)

------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the issue.
The exploded war's lib had a jar file that was corrupted.
Manually downloading and copying that jar, in webapps fixed the issue.

Thanks all for the support!!

Comment: How did you find out which file was corrupted? I'm having the same problem..... please explain

Comment: @kamokaze: Looked at jar sizes in the webapps folder of other deployed servers(test, staging). Found the difference in one jar size on my local (which was picked from local .m2) and copied the same jar from test server. It fixed things. Also maybe unrelated, but if this does not work, can you look for duplicate versions of one jar? I've found maven sometimes picks one version that is not required. Hope to know if your issue is fixed.

Comment: If you use maven for project run ' mvn clean compile' and maven show you corrupted file stored in your local repo which was copied to the war file and damaged the package

Answer (score 0):

How do you deploy your app ?
What exactly do you put into webapps folder, a file with zip extension, a file with war extension, or an exploaded war folder ?

Try changing extension from zip to war.

If you use zip or war file, try to unzip it by ourself.
If on windows, change extension to zip and open with windows explorer, if on linux try unzip command. If you cannot unzip by hand it means there is sth nok with your app, the zip file is corrupted, eg only partially downloaded.

Try reading https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html .

Comment: I use an exploded war(already mentioned in question). No zip is there inside the tomcat itself, i searched for it. :(. The war un-tars and deploys and i can do it manually too.